# T-SQL Concatenate & group multiple rows into a single row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to group whilst also concatenating rows into a comma separated string.
Example:

```
Name            Place
Steve Jones     New York
Steve Jones     Washington
Albert Smith    Miami
Albert Smith    Denver
```

to ...

```
Steve Jones    New York, Washington
Albert Smith   Miami, Denver
```

Greatly appreciated

Comment: @Muguel TSQL is not used by MySQL

Comment: This is generally MUCH easier to do at the display layer (web page, report, app, whatever) than in SQL.  It's _possible_ but TSQL does not have a clean syntax to do string aggregation.

Answer (score 8):

If you use SQL Server 2008 and above, you can use STUFF and XML PATH to get the result you want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
    , STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + Place
        FROM YourTable t1
        where t1.Name = t2.Name
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS Places
FROM YourTable t2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CROSS APPLY and FOR XML PATH:

```
SELECT distinct PP.Name, SUBSTRING(A.Places, 0, LEN(A.Places)) AS CombinedPlaces
FROM PersonPlace PP
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT place + ', ' 
    FROM PersonPlace AS AP
    WHERE AP.Name = PP.Name
    FOR XML PATH('')        
) A(places)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String_Agg if you are using 2017, SQL Azure else you can query as below:

```
Select [Name],
    Places = Stuff((Select ', '+Place from yourtable where [Name] = t.[Name] for xml path('')),1,2,'')
    from yourtable
    group by [Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a simpler way, but this works:

```
with N as
(
    select name, count(*) over (partition by name order by name) c from PersonPlace
),

Q as
(
    select J.name, J.place, cast(J.place as varchar) place_name, J.c cnt, 1 c from
        (select distinct(name) from PersonPlace) K
            cross apply
            (
                select top 1 P.*, N.c from PersonPlace P
                    inner join N on N.name = P.name

                where P.name = K.name
            ) J

    union all
        select P.name, P.place, cast(Q.place + ', ' + P.place as varchar), Q.cnt, Q.c + 1  

             from PersonPlace P 
                inner join Q on Q.name = P.name and Q.c + 1 <= cnt and P.place <> Q.place

)

select Q.name, Q.place_name from Q where Q.c  = Q.cnt
```

Results:

```
name            place_name
--------------  ----------------------
Steve Jones     New York, Washington  
Albert Smith    Denver, Miami
```

**[Rextest Demo](http://rextester.com/BAL75623)**

If the `People` and `Places` are actually separate tables with their own keys,  then we can simply quite a bit.